# Why does R coerce argument "double" into logical?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe containing column `df$a` containing 3 possible values: `(0,1,NA...)` and `class(df$a) - numeric`

I have defined a new variable, identifying groups which contain `df$a >0` at least for one row.

```
df[,b:=+(any(a,na.rm=TRUE)>0),by=group]
```

I am expecting `df$b` to be either 0 or 1, but instead R is returning TRUE and FALSE with a warning "coercing argument of type "double" to logical".

I have tried to write the same code using `ifelse`, `max(a,na.rm=TRUE)>0`, `any(a,na.rm=TRUE)==1`, etc, but all returns with TRUE and FALSE instead of 1 and 0.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: you mean you tried `df[,b:=+(max(a,na.rm=TRUE)>0), by=group]` but you still got TRUE/FALSE? I cannot replicate that. If you wanted to use `any()` need to move the comparison inside the expression: `df[,b:=+(any(a>0, na.rm=TRUE)), by=group]`. It's the `+` that turns the logical value to a numeric value

Comment: Hi, yes I did try both on my data and still got TRUE/FALSE. Trouble is that I cannot provide a reproducible example because any simple dataframe I make seem to work with any and max, but my real dataframe (in a remote server therefore cannot be exported out) is still returning TRUE and FALSE. I have just made an additional 1*variable to make it 1 and 0 for now, but it is very perplexing.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is

```
df[,b:=+(any(a>0, na.rm=TRUE)), by=group]
```

If you do `any(c(1,3,5))` you get the same error. `any` expects logical value, not numeric (Double) valeue, so it coerces 1, 3, and 5 to logical values and throws that warning. Instead if you did `any(c(1,3,5) > 4)` you now have a comparison in the `any()` and the `>` will return TRUE or FALSE so no warning is returned.

In order to turn TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 you can use the unary `+` operator. But the warning is coming from the `any()`

Tested with

```
df <- data.table(a=c(1, 1, NA, 0, NA, 0), group=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
```